# Why does GCC's __attribute__((...)) syntax use double parentheses?

Tags: c, gcc

The [documentation for GCC's `__attribute__((...))` syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html) indicates that attributes must be surrounded by double parentheses, but does not give a rationale for this design decision.

What practical reason would have caused GCC's designers to require this? Does it have anything to do with the preprocessor's handling of double parentheses?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To make it easier to eliminate it for different compiler. If you have portable code, you have to remove them for other compilers, so you do

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif
```

The problem is that attributes have various number of arguments and you can combine multiple attributes in one `__attribute__` declaration, but C only introduced variadic macros in C99. With double parenthesis the above definition does not need variadic macros.

Answer (score 18):

probably the idea is that you can declare a simple macro that helps to ignore all this in any other C and C++ compiler. If you wouldn't have the second pair of parenthesis that macro would be necessarily one with `...`. So for compilers that don't support that you would be screwed.

*Edit:* With this syntax it can simply look like

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define attribute(X) __attribute__(X)
#else
# define attribute(X)
#endif
```

and then you would use `attribute` for your function declarations, e.g.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to define a macro name that starts with a double underscore.

Comment: @dreamlax, I know. I didn't say that one should do this, but what I think was the idea behind it.